# Change Order of Tuple Values within a List of a list

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples inside a list like this:

```
[[('2375', 'AddressNumber'),
  ('Second', 'StreetName'),
  ('Street', 'StreetNamePostType')],
 [('401', 'AddressNumber'),
  ('Wilmington', 'StreetName'),
  ('Drive', 'StreetNamePostType')],
   ... ],
 ...]
```

And need to change the order of the values like this:

```
[[('AddressNumber', '2375'),
  ('StreetName', 'Second'),
  ('StreetNamePostType', 'Street')],
 [('AddressNumber', '401'),
  ('StreetName', 'Wilmington'),
  ('StreetNamePostType', 'Drive')],
   ... ],
 ...]
```

I realize that it's immutable and I think I need to change this to a list but the list within a list is throwing me off in my python script. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: for reference, please share your attempted *code* with us, as it makes it easier to figure out where the issue maybe. and SO has many related problems/solutions to this question, better research would save time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I realize that it's immutable and I think I need to change this to a list

No; you just need to create a *new* tuple instead of trying to mutate the existing one.

> but the list within a list is throwing me off in my python script.

So, take it a step at a time, and work from the inside out.

First, let's define something that can create the reversed version of one of the tuples:

```
def flip_address_data(data): # 1A
    value, label = data
    return label, value
```

Or, without naming the values:

```
def flip_address_data(data): # 1B
    return data[::-1]
```

Then we can write the code to replace each item in the inner list:

```
def flip_inner_list(l): # 2A 
    l[:] = [flip_address_data(d) for d in l]
```

(Or, if you prefer, the procedural way using `enumerate` to get the indices to write back:)

```
def flip_inner_list(l): # 2B
    for i, d in enumerate(l):
        l[i] = flip_address_data(d)
```

Finally the same for the outer list:

```
def flip_outer_list(l): # 3A
    l[:] = [flip_inner_list(i) for i in l]
```

(or similarly:)

```
def flip_outer_list(l): # 3B
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        l[i] = flip_inner_list(x)
```

Once you're comfortable with it, you can condense the process. For example, it's easy to just substitute 1B into 2A:

```
def flip_inner_list(l): # 2C
    l[:] = [d[::-1] for d in l]
```

Rather than assigning back into the original lists, it will be easier to just create new data:

```
def flip_inner_list(l): # modify 2C to return the value
    return [d[::-1] for d in l]

def flip_outer_list(l): # similarly modifying 3A
    return [flip_inner_list(i) for i in l]
```

Once we have the mindset of creating new values instead of modifying old ones, the substitution step becomes easy again:

```
def flip_outer_list(l): # using full-sized names for clarity
    return [[item[::-1] for item in inner] for inner in l]
```

Comment: Thank you for the awesome explanation. I had to test each section out to see how it really works so I can wrap my head around it but now I understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
xxx = [[('2375', 'AddressNumber'),
        ('Second', 'StreetName'),
        ('Street', 'StreetNamePostType')],
       [('401', 'AddressNumber'),
        ('Wilmington', 'StreetName'),
        ('Drive', 'StreetNamePostType')]]

[[(x[1],x[0]) for x in tt] for tt in xxx]
```

Output

```
[[('AddressNumber', '2375'), 
  ('StreetName', 'Second'), 
  ('StreetNamePostType', 'Street')], 
 [('AddressNumber', '401'), 
  ('StreetName', 'Wilmington'), 
  ('StreetNamePostType', 'Drive')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibly way is this:

```
outerList = [[('2375', 'AddressNumber'),('Second', 'StreetName'),('Street', 'StreetNamePostType')], [('401', 'AddressNumber'),('Wilmington', 'StreetName'),('Drive', 'StreetNamePostType')]]

print([[swapVals[::-1] for swapVals in element] for element in outerList])
### use the slice approach to reverse the elements within each set of the nested list.
```

Output:

```
[[('AddressNumber', '2375'), ('StreetName', 'Second'), ('StreetNamePostType', 'Street')], [('AddressNumber', '401'), ('StreetName', 'Wilmington'), ('StreetNamePostType', 'Drive')]]
```